# Error: Failed to transpile program - Ionic 3 error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, transpiler

I got the project from github, try to install the app on android devices and getting following error.

> Error: Failed to transpile program

Here is my ionic info command information.

```
global packages:
    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.2.0
    Cordova CLI      : 8.0.0
    Ionic CLI        : 3.2.0
local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1
    Cordova Platforms  : android 5.2.1
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.5.0
System:
    Node       : v10.14.1
    OS         : Windows 10
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
```

I tried all the possibilities (install and uninstall the appscripts, ionic, cordova and npm) and no luck. Anybody have any idea about this or facing this problem before?

Thanks
Ak

Comment: Have you tried running `ionic doctor check` command?

Comment: Ionic version is 3.2.0. I think doctor check command won't run it

Comment: can you use cordova 6.5.0, it is better

Comment: No luck, same error.                                                                                 
    global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.2.0
    Cordova CLI      : 6.5.0
    Ionic CLI        : 3.2.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1
    Cordova Platforms  : android 5.2.1
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.5.0

System:

    Node       : v10.14.1
    OS         : Windows 10
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed

Comment: Try updating cordova android. The current version is 7.1 and you're using 5.2